# Fluid Layout vs Grid?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, grid-layout, baseline

I feel like I missed a memo or something. Are fluid layouts and grid layouts the same thing? What is this baseline thing I keep hearing about? Is the baseline just like something you create to line up all the words and pictures? How is that any different than just floating/clearing and using percentage widths?

Is this just revised terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fluid layouts and grid layouts are essentially css starting points - most css grids can be used with either fluid widths or fixed widths

[boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

[960.gs](http://960.gs/)

[baseline css](http://baselinecss.com/)

are a few that I can think of - they're designed to help designers / developers to quickly  and simply create consistant layouts

Comment: ah so a grid layout can be fluid or not. Is a grid layout just what we normally do when developing a page with divs and normal positioning? When are we not using a grid layout when we develop a web page?

Comment: effectively yes - the main purpose of grid layouts as I understand it is consistency and re-usability.
yes grid layouts can be fluid http://grids.heroku.com can be used to generate fixed and fluid 960.gs grids - if you're looking into grids it's not a bad place to start